# Apple LLVM compiler 3.1 error - iOS 5; Xcode 4.3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, llvm-3.0

I have been receiving this error for a long time and I don't know what to do.

In order to keep the question short, I have written the error into a .rtf file and put it into CloudApp. Here's the link: http://cl.ly/0T3n1Q123u352T372t0m

I think it has something to do with "CLAPIDeserializer.m".

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

**ERROR:**

> CompileC
>   /Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CLAPIDeserializer.o
>   "Cloud/API Parsing/CLAPIDeserializer.m" normal armv7 objective-c
>   com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
>       cd "/Users/juniorpond/Documents/Dropbox/Triple J Studios/Applications/Applications/CloudSend/Test/Test"
>       setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -x objective-c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk
>   -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -mthumb "-DIBOutlet=**attribute**((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=**attribute**((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))"
>   "-DIBAction=void)**attribute**((ibaction)" -miphoneos-version-min=5.1
>   -iquote /Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Test-generated-files.hmap
>   -I/Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Test-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Test-all-target-headers.hmap
>   -iquote /Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Test-project-headers.hmap
>   -I/Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include
>   -I/Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/DerivedSources/armv7
>   -I/Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/DerivedSources
>   -F/Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -include /Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/Test-Prefix-clsydhfesjzmtrbgszvgmeofhzfq/Test-Prefix.pch
>   -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CLAPIDeserializer.d
>   --serialize-diagnostics /Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CLAPIDeserializer.dia
>   -c "/Users/juniorpond/Documents/Dropbox/Triple J Studios/Applications/Applications/CloudSend/Test/Test/Cloud/API
>   Parsing/CLAPIDeserializer.m" -o
>   /Users/juniorpond/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Test-fqacaiejputxwicubwhguzleizde/Build/Intermediates/Test.build/Debug-iphoneos/Test.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CLAPIDeserializer.o
>
> clang: error: unable to execute command: posix_spawn failed: Resource
>   temporarily unavailable clang: error: clang frontend command failed
>   due to signal 1 (use -v to see invocation) clang: note: diagnostic
>   msg: Please submit a bug report to
>   http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and include command line
>   arguments and all diagnostic information. clang: error: unable to
>   execute command: posix_spawn failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
>   clang: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
>   Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 255

Comment: Is this a project you made or one that you downloaded?  It looks like one of the pre or post build scripts is unable to run.

Comment: This is from CloudApp. [link](https://github.com/cloudapp/objective-c)

Answer (score 24):

When this happens, close xcode and issue the "purge" command in Terminal then restart xcode. That solved this error for me.

Comment: @ademar111190: type "purge" (without quotes) in Terminal then press ENTER.

Comment: @openfrog: With purge method you don't need to restart

Answer (score 22):

It means your OS X kernel cannot spawn any more processes for your user ID. There is a maximum number of processes per user:

To see your process limitation:

```
sysctl kern.maxprocperuid
```

To check how many processes you have running:

```
ps aux | grep username | wc -l
```

To see how many zombie process:

```
ps -v -u username | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | grep Z | wc -l
```

To see what they are:

```
for pid in `ps -v -u username | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1, $2}' | grep Z  | awk '{print $1}'`
do
  ps -o command="" -p $pid >> zombies.txt
done
```

None of these processes can be killed, and purge won't work on my mac, 10.8.2.

You could temporarily increase the max user processes count:

```
sudo sysctl -w kern.maxprocperuid=1024
```

Then in your .bash_profile or .bashrc add:

```
ulimit -u 1024
```

And change Finder’s limits:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxproc 1024
```

But really, it's time for coffee and give your mac a reboot..

Comment: Thank you. This was the most complete and insightful answer.

Comment: Nobel prize for you man, I was thinking that I really kill my MacBook sometimes. Now I understand him:) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem with a project that I have under GIT with some of my team, the problem was that some of my team forgot to commit some new added files.

So, the .xcodeproj project it self was taking into consideration that it has some ViewControllers, but they weren't physically exist.

As soon as I added the missing view controllers, the project got built properly.

Hope this can help your situation.

Answer (score 2):

just do it!!

1.Turn off your mac computer.

2.Turn on mac computer.

3.Run XCode

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a clean to fix this.  product>clean from xcode.  rebooting & purging didn't help, cleaning fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The message says

> clang frontend command failed due to signal 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Try adding a "-v" to your "Other C Flags" under Build Settings of your project and see what it spits out...